# return in if jumps to return on the end of the method

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, return

I want to create a binarySearch algorithm as recursion.
The code should be ok, since everything is working as i want it to.

This is my code:

```
public class Searcher {

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int binarySearchRecursive(T[] values, T key) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = values.length - 1;
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;

        return binarySearchRecursive(values, key, start, end, mid);
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int binarySearchRecursive(T[] values, T key, int start, int end, int mid) {
        if (key.compareTo(values[mid]) == 0) {
            return mid;
        } else if (key.compareTo(values[mid]) < 0) {
            end = mid;
            mid = (start + end) / 2;
            binarySearchRecursive(values, key, start, end, mid);
        } else if (key.compareTo(values[mid]) > 0) {
            start = mid;
            mid = (start + end) / 2;
            binarySearchRecursive(values, key, start, end, mid);
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

The test for it is the following:

```
class SearcherTest {
    private Integer[] values;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        values = new Integer[]{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11};
    }

    @Test
    void binarySearchRecursive() {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            assertEquals(i, Searcher.binarySearchRecursive(values, values[i]),
                    "binary search should return index for included values");
        }

        assertEquals(-1, Searcher.binarySearchRecursive(values, 100),
                "binary search should return -1 for not included values");
    }
}
```

While debugging, everything works as intended.
Although after jumping in the if
`if (key.compareTo(values[mid]) == 0) {`
`return mid;` is executed, but jumps immediately to the return -1 on the end and doesnt give the wanted mid int back.

How could i solve it and give mid back instead of -1?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: return mid does NOT jump to return -1. it returns the value of mid, and ends the method

Comment: I think you want to have `return binarySearchRecursive(…)`, otherwise you will only ever return `mid` OR -1. Put differently: you are never doing anything with the returned `mid`

Comment: @Stultuske That what i would want, but it doesnt return the value of mid and doesn't end the method. Thats the problem.

Comment: @TS98 no. That's impossible. the moment you hit return mid, it returns mid. What happens in a next call of the method is not related to this.

Comment: ok yeah, that true. I guess i explained my problem wrong but its still this problem.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have a rather simple mistake you just forgot to return the value from the recursion.

simply adding a return statment before the call to `binarySearchRecursive(values, key, start, end, mid);` should fix it.

so your code would look like this:

```java
public class Searcher {

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int binarySearchRecursive(T[] values, T key) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = values.length - 1;
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;

        return binarySearchRecursive(values, key, start, end, mid);
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int binarySearchRecursive(T[] values, T key, int start, int end, int mid) {
        if (key.compareTo(values[mid]) == 0) {
            return mid;
        } else if (key.compareTo(values[mid]) < 0) {
            end = mid;
            mid = (start + end) / 2;
            return binarySearchRecursive(values, key, start, end, mid);
        } else if (key.compareTo(values[mid]) > 0) {
            start = mid;
            mid = (start + end) / 2;
            return binarySearchRecursive(values, key, start, end, mid);
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

hope this helps!
happy coding!

EDIT:
To clear up some missunderstanding, in the debugger it doesn't just jump out of the `if`-statment when hitting the return. it leaves the method and enteres the method where it left of previously. this is best explaned with an example.

if we have a tree like this:

```
     3
   /   \
  1     5 
 / \   / \
0   2 4   6
```

and want to find the value 2, we start at the top (mid)
we see that 2 != 3 so we go left.
we need to expicitly tell the computer to return our anwser even if it is not currently found, because we will only find it once we have done some recursion steps.
when we are at the left branch we see that 2 != 1 and go right.
again we need to expicitly tell the computer to return the answer it find's in that branch of the tree, since we are not there yet.
now when we get to 2 == 2 the anwser is accepted, but returning it we only get back one layer in the recurison.
as mentioned before we need to propagate the result we got to the top by keep returning it.

if this is still a bit confusion you may need to learn a bit about how recursion works (mainly the stack which is used)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not working. The recursion is working fine and i only want to return the int mid if the key = value on index mid.

Comment: @TS98 well mid should be getting returned, but for a binary-search the method should return the mid of the left or right branch if it is not located at the current node. I'm not quite sure about what you have troubles with, could you elaborate?

Comment: I can try atleast:

When im debugging my code, i can see that if the if statement is true (key = value of the current element in the array) it goes into the method body (to the return mid). Thats what i would want. Instead of returning mid, it jumps to the return statement on the end and returns -1 and i have no idea why.

Comment: oh I see, I think I get it now.

Comment: @TS98  it is *jumping* to the `return -1` of the previous call after returning from the recursive call (original code) - as answered here, you need to return the value from the recursive call... but it is still missing the case when the value is not found (what to do if `start` == `end` or similar)